# Return value in Catch Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to create a generic service to fetch some settings from the server. When an error occurs I would like to catch this error and return a default value (locally I have a default configuration that should be used when an error occurs).

Since I am using `Angular 4.3.6` I can use the new `HttpClientModule`.

**The code:**

```
/**
  * Fetches the map settings
  * @returns { Observable<MapConfiguration> }
  */

public getMapConfiguration(): Observable<MapConfiguration> {
  return this.http.get<MapConfiguration>(MapService.MAPSETTINGSURL)
    .catch((exception) => {
      console.warn('Could not fetch map configuration due to: ', exception);
      return new MapConfiguration();
    });
}
```

This code gives the following error:

`Type 'MapConfiguration' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.`

I am new to Observables (used to promises) and with a promise I could return a value in the catch. How can I solve this problem, so that there is always a value returned?

*I would like to make the service handle the error and not the `subscriber`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have always a returning value you can wrap it as observable by using `return Observable.of(new MapConfiguration());` in your catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Observable.of(new MapConfiguration());
```

to generate an error with your object as a message

```
return Observable.throw(new MapConfiguration());
```